# Create a list of sums from a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working on experimental data where I create a temperature profile from 45 °C to 5 °C and then again to 45 °C.
Plotting the data results in a loop, since cooling from 45 °C to 5 °C and heating from 5° C to 45 °C are recorded. But since I need to the plot to appear "chronological" every temperature needs to be unique.

The image shows a visual explanation of what I need.
[image: Visual explanation]

What I did therefore is getting the difference from each consecutive temperature interval using numpys "diff" function. So far so good.
Now to make a useful plot out of this I need to somehow create a new list where every item is the sum from the ones before.

A small example of what I'm looking for:

```
my_list = [1,2,5,1,4,2,3]
#some operation
result_list = [1,3,8,9,13,15,18]
```

Would be great if someone knows how to do that or has a smarter idea how to get the job done!

Comment: `np.cumsum(my_list)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this question is tagged `numpy` but for some reason nobody posts the numpy solution... use [`numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html). :)

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,5,1,4,2,3] # could also be a numpy array
>>> np.cumsum(my_list)
array([ 1,  3,  8,  9, 13, 15, 18])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice feature from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) called [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) that does exactly that:

```
from itertools import accumulate

lst = [1,2,5,1,4,2,3]
result_list = list(accumulate(lst))
print(result_list)  # -> [1, 3, 8, 9, 13, 15, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1,2,5,1,4,2,3]
result_list = [my_list[0]]

for i in my_list[1:]:
    result_list.append(result_list[-1] + i)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: this is a bit *hacky*. using `enumerate` would be more straightforward.

Comment: Ya I was gonna delete this, but kept it since already a better answer was selected.